# Why is Captain America's shield called indestructible if Vibranium can be broken down for microscopic applications?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-age-of-ultron

First, "if Vibranium is indestructible, how was Captain America's shield created (melting and hammering shouldn't work)?" type questions should be trivial. the answer would be similar to that of Adamantium: Just after extraction, it can be moulded just once. The shape would be permanent after that.

(If answer is different for Vibranium, let me know)

But, in *Avengers: Age of Ultron* movie,

> Vibranium was used to create Vision's muscular body. Ultron took Vibranium rods from black market and later we saw that Vibranium was combining well with biological artificial tissues.

Now, the question is: How is such application of Vibranium possible if Vibranium is indestructible? Why is Captain America's shield, supposedly, indestructible?

Comment: Hmm, was going to say [dupe](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/73057/21267), but the question seems different enough that it isn't. Just to clarify, you're asking "Once the Vibranium is **set**, how can you manipulate it **afterwards**?"; correct?

Comment: Did he definitely get the vibranium in solid form? Was it not stored as a liquid? (I really need to see this movie again.)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Haha.. Seriously? Did those little transparent cylinders look any special to maintain Vibranium's liquidity?

Comment: “In normal room condition, it's solid.” Is that actually stated in the MCU?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite We actually see that..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### Captain America's shield in the Marvel Cinematic Universe (Earth-199999) is NOT indestructible; far from it. Created by Howard Stark from a vibranium alloy, the MCU shield is very tough but nowhere near as durable as Captain America's shield in the comics. With sufficient force or continued bombardment, a shield composed of only vibranium can be destroyed as the vibranium destabilizes.

**Marvel Wikia [Vibranium](http://marvel.wikia.com/Vibranium) entry:**

> - Vibranium is not as hard or dense as Adamantium, but it is still very durable. It is also easier to make objects out of, such as the mesh costume the Black Panther wears. Vibranium absorbs more impact than adamantium.
> - The apparent observable vibratory rate of the molecules of the Vibranium itself does not noticeably increase when the Vibranium absorbs mechanical energy. The outside vibratory energy is stored within the bonds between the molecules making up the Vibranium.
> - As a result, a chunk of Vibranium which had absorbed a considerable amount of vibratory energy would be exceedingly hard to demolish. **If enough force were were applied to this chunk to smash it, the Vibranium would explode, releasing much of the absorbed energy.**

[image]

- Captain America's MCU shield is composed singularly from a vibranium-metallic alloy. Durable, tough, damage resistant, capable of taking a hit from even Mjolnir, but far weaker than the comic version of Cap's shield.

[image]

- In the comic universe, Captain America's shield is made from an Adamantium-Vibranium alloy which on Earth is considered to be one of the most durable and nigh-indestructible things ever made on Earth. Attempts to replicate the nature of this Proto-Adamantium shield led to the creation of True Adamantium, the second most indestructible material on Earth.

[image]

- In 1985′s Captain America #303, we meet MacLain again, who, we learn, created Captain America’s shield…and yes, in MacLain notes we learn the shield is composed of adamantium/something-something/vibranium/iron alloy. We are never told what the X-element which allowed proto-adamantium to exist.

Comment: So...it's a bomb. Like, straight up, hit it hard enough and it unleashes hellish levels of energy in an explosion. That's a bomb more or less by definition

Comment: That's American freedom and democracy for ya

Answer (score 11):

Indestructible is probably the wrong word. As you say, indestructible means no force can change it whatsoever, which obviously isn't true.

Vibranium can be melted and shaped (just like Adamantium). However, like Adamantium, it has extremely high tensile strength. When solid, it is virtually impossible to dent, bend, crack, or break. This is why people call it "indestructible."

> Additionally, Vibranium absorbs KINETIC energy directed at it, not thermal Therefore, the more it's being impacted or hit, the stronger and more durable it becomes for the time being. [Omegacron's comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87474/why-is-captain-americas-shield-called-indestructible-if-vibranium-can-be-broken#comment192328_87475)

We know that Captain America's shield has withstood the following forces

- Bullets
- Explosions (including a Chitauri grenade)
- Impact from great heights (falling)
- Thor's hammer (which was able to destroy the Rainbow Bridge)

**So maybe it would be better to call it unbreakable (meaning its shaped cannot be changed or broke due to blunt force).**

Adamantium is ferromagnetic, and therefore given enough force (say Magneto) it can be ripped apart. We don't know if this is true for Vibranium ( [Is Magneto able to manipulate Vibranium?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/26451/is-magneto-able-to-manipulate-vibranium) )

**If Vibranium was truly indestructible, then it would only be seen in its natural form as an ore, and would be un-shapeable and probably unusable. Unless we happened to find a shield shaped piece of ore somewhere.**

Comment: Means, enemy just needs a lightsaber. Right? I don't think so.

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 Maybe. Maybe Vibranium has certain thermal properties that take it a long long time to heat up, and so a quick swipe with a lightsaber wouldn't be effective because the heat would be dispersed too quickly to allow it to melt it.

Comment: @JackBNimble good answer. You should add that Vibranium absorbs KINETIC energy directed at it, not thermal. Therefore, the more it's being impacted or hit, the stronger and more durable it becomes for the time being. Therefore it can be melted under the correct circumstances. Bringing it UP to temperature, like throwing it into the sun or molten metal, for instance, would probably do it. A flamethrower or lightsaber, not so much.

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 : in that example, the kinetic force being applied to the lightsaber blade (such as the Jedi pushing towards the shield) would simply make the vibranium stronger and therefore negate any heat the lightsaber blade generated. And lightsaber blades only generate heat under very specific conditions.

Comment: @Omegacron done.

Answer (score 1):

Captain America's shield is not Vibranium but an alloy of Adamantium and Vibranium known as Proto-Adamantium, although Vibranium and Adamantium are durable they are not invincible so the shield could have been formed before the metals had finished alloying.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Do you have a source for this statement?

Comment: This sentiment seems to be from the comics, however the MCU continuity is slightly varied on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Well the word alloy initially implies by definition more than one metal as the source material. The fact the term Vibranium alloy is used doesn't mean that the movie shield isn't an alloy of Adamantium and vVbranium. They may simply still be treading on the Marvel Universe licensing line between Fox "X-men movie rights" Disney's "MCU Movie rights". Actually a clever way of letting you know while staying within the lines. Thanks juyaku
As an extra note it should be referenced that after the shield is broken that it is also reforged with Asgardian Uru by Tony Stark and the dwarves from Nidavellir after the events of the fear itself storyline. Should be interesting to see if they work any of that into the MCU.