# Is there something in the Marvel universe that could cut vibranium in half?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, avengers-age-of-ultron

In [Avengers: Age of Ultron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avengers:_Age_of_Ultron), when Scarlet Witch tampers with Tony Stark's mind, he sees a nightmare of dead Avengers. There, you see Captain America's shield torn in half. It was like something cut it or broke it.

[image]

If vibranium is indestructible, then what could do this to the shield? Is there any weapon or person which is able to damage vibranium?

I'm not a fan of comics, so I don't know if there's been a mention of this.

Comment: This question has some info: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87474/why-is-captain-americas-shield-called-indestructible-if-vibranium-can-be-broken?rq=1

Comment: The short answer is "pretty much anything can break it".

Comment: "anything can break it"?!?! so why do they call it INDESTRUCTIBLE?

Comment: It's a relative term. Is anything indestructible? The word exists all the same.

Comment: As such this question is a bit of a duplicate... The linked question asks about Vibranium's indestructibility. It should be modified to ask about what could potentially break it in the cinematic universe.

Comment: Black Panther put some pretty deep scratches in CA's shield, I wonder what dem claws are made of!

Comment: Those claws are made of Vibranium B, a material capable of destroying most metals including Vibranium A.

Comment: This answer is a duplicate of: [Why is Captain America's Shield called indestructible if Vibranium can be broken?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87474/why-is-captain-americas-shield-called-indestructible-if-vibranium-can-be-broken?rq=1). I am not sure why it wasn't closed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the Infinity Gauntlet comic series Thanos was able to smash Captain America's shield. Admittedly at that point he had the full gauntlet.

[image]

So if the Infinity Stones confer similar power levels in the MCU then Thanos could do it.

Comment: This is probably the most relevant answer, since Thanos and the stones are involved in the story-line

Answer (score 6):

With the release of *Avengers: Endgame*, we now have confirmation that Thanos is capable of doing exactly this when he puts his mind to it, and he doesn't even have Infinity Stones at that point. Just his brutal strength and double-bladed sword are enough.

Comment: It's worth noting that his sword is apparently made of Uru so it could be Uru that is capable of cutting Vibranium not Thanos' raw strength.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know the material is stated anywhere. Was that mentioned in the movies themselves or some supplementary material?

Comment: Mentioned here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/212153/58193

Answer (score 4):

In the "Fear Itself" story arch, #5, the shield was broken by the Serpent, who is an Asgardian god.

The story shows Capt. America throwing his shield to the Serpent, who catches it, then shatters it like glass. (see below)

[image: Serpent Break Shield]

There is another example, but I will link the article where I got the pic from, for the other one :[Broken Shield](http://comicvine.gamespot.com/articles/off-my-mind-what-if-captain-americas-shield-breaks/1100-143453/)

Comment: I can't say I'm surprised, but the runes the serpent speaks are complete and utter gibberish: zw sjrfer (they're in Elder Futhark, the j rune, pronounced y, isn't found in any other futharks). It's possible there's some sort of ciphering going on, but as the cipher runes used by the norse were new symbols that described the position of the intended rune in the futhark, rather than using an existing rune to represent another I think it's pretty unlikely

Answer (score 4):

Vibranium, while very tough, isn't usually described as indestructible (that's reserved for the equally fictional metal, adamantium). Even such ultra-strong metals can be broken by individuals or gadgets that can mess with matter at the atomic (or sub-atomic) level. Thanos breaking Cap's shield is doing it with his glowing gauntlet, so is probably destroying it with infinity gem energy, not through brute force.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I have found exactly what you want, caps shield in half,

[image]

Another individual from Asgard, the Serpent is exactly as strong and menacing as he sounds. He is the God of Fear and was freed during an "event" comic. He begins to turn Marvel heroes into his mindless minions. Naturally, it's up to the Avengers to bring down this tyrant. During the epic battle, Captain America throws his mighty shield at the Serpent, but instead of taking a beating, Serpent just catches the shield and snaps it in half with his bare hands. Luckily for Cap, after Serpent is defeated, some dwarves repaired the shield which left a scar on it from then on.

Cited from [this website.](https://www.therichest.com/expensive-lifestyle/entertainment/11-villains-you-didnt-know-broke-captain-americas-shield/)