# What is Thanos' sword made of?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

Towards the end of *Avengers: Endgame*, we see

> Thanos fighting Captain America. He repeatedly hits Cap's shield with a big double sword thing, which breaks the shield.

How did this happen? As far as I know, we've never seen anything that can damage

> vibranium before in the MCU. Black Panther's vibranium suit is not obviously damaged when hit (admittedly just once, remotely) with Thanos’s sword in the battle. Is the sword made from a hitherto unknown metal?
>  [image: Thanos wielding double-sword!]

Comment: Your assumption is quite flawed.. Corvus Glaive's blade goes right through Vision's body.. And Vision is made of vibranium. Moreover, didn't Thanos rip off the mind stone from vision's forehead with his bare hands?

Comment: Also vibranium isn't indestructible, just **very tough** and it hasn't been hit with a giant sword wielded by a Titan on the **edge** before.

Comment: @Shreedhar: he sure did! I'm not sure Vision is all-vibranium. We know vibranium was definitely involved in making him, but so was Dr Cho's cradle that did... something to meld organic and non-organic material, so I'm not sure he's 100% vibranium, unlike Cap's shield and (I think) Black Panther's suit.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite well, the MCU has established that Vibranium is the strongest metal on Earth. However, there is no proof that it's the strongest in the universe (not counting the comics here).

Comment: Also also, apart from vibranium, vision has only organic tissue over his vibranium shell. so Glaive's blade kinda cut through vibranium once.. So if thanos is giving around vibranium-cutting weapons to his thugs, I'm sure he has something much better kept for himself

Comment: “vision has only organic tissue over his vibranium shell” — where is that stated in the movies? I accept Thanos and co. can have weapons that can damage vibranium, I'm just not sure Vision is evidence of that.

Comment: Related answer in: [Why is Captain America's shield called indestructible if Vibranium can be broken down for microscopic applications?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/87530/56571)

Comment: "we've never seen anything that can damage vibranium before in the MCU" - don't we see the shield get scratched by black panther's claws in Civil War?

Comment: @Chris: possibly (unless it's just paint coming off), although Black Panther's claws are made of vibranium too. See https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/184129/how-does-black-panther-leave-scratches-on-captain-americas-shield-in-civil-war

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: My belief is that the shield itself was scratched demonstrating how dangerous BP's claws are. And yeah, they are made of vibranium but that's kind of my point - we have seen things that can damage the shield before so its not unreasonable to believe that there are more things that can. And given how much of space Thanos had crusaded over it is perhaps not that surprising that his weapon is one of the best available in the universe.

Comment: @Chris: we've seen that vibranium can damage vibranium. That's a bit different than seeing any other material damage it, given that vibranium is described as the strongest material.

Comment: But that then just leads to the obvious answer that Thanos's weapon was made of vibranium or something unknown on earth that is stronger (eg that question you linked mentions that in comics alloys of vibranium are stronger). Given that there are seemingly ways on earth that would damage the shield I see no reason to think that Thanos wouldn't have access to such things too.

Comment: And to address the comment on black panther's suit a single blow could easily be not enough - caps shield took repeated blows and the first ones do only do very small damage - I first noticed this when thanos's weapon bites just a very short distance into the top of cap's shield. Also BP's suit is clearly not the same as the shield since it is flexible and not solid and also has a bunch of technology built in such as the energy burst stuff.

Comment: I should note also that I am not adding an answer to the question because I can't actually cite anything that discusses what Thanos's weapon is made of or anything like that to say it is definitely made of X, etc. To me it just doesn't seem that much of a mystery.

Comment: Related: [How can Captain America's shield get damaged?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/99813/49)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I do believe that Vibranium is the strongest element **only on earth!**

In Infinity war, we see Corvus Glaive cleave straight through Vision as if he were made of butter.

Considering that, it's not so surprising that Thanos would have the element himself.

After all, why would he entrust the strongest weapon only to one of his lackies... errr... I mean, kids, and not himself?

Comment: Worth noting that Vision is not just made of Vibranium, in fact considering the amount of Vibranium Ultron got I would imagine Vision is mostly made of the stuff Helen prints.

Comment: Helen just had a mechanism to print stuff. In the case of Vision, she just printed it. The source material was Vibranium all along. Ultron did manage to get his hands on a sizeable amount of Vibranium, judging by the shipping crate he "bought" from Klau.

Comment: I thought he only got a few vials of vibranium but yeah there might have been more.

Comment: You also have to remember Corvus Glaive's glaive is the sharpest thing in the known universe according to the lore and can cut through anything.

Comment: Civil War showed that vibranium is capable of damaging other vibranium as Black Panther's claws left visible marks on the shield. The Black Panther movie also showed that vibranium originally came from space so it's not unreasonable to assume that other space-faring cultures have had access to the element at some point. Therefore, it's not unreasonable to speculate that Thanos' sword might have been made of vibranium as well.

Comment: @aleppke great additions! You can put this up as your own answer :)

Comment: _"Bruce Banner: I don't follow. What comes out of Wakanda? [looking at Steve's shield]

Tony Stark: The strongest metal on Earth.

Avengers: Age of Ultron"_ If you want a quote to back up your first statement.

Answer (score 14):

This was (indirectly) addressed by the film's directors in an interview with [Comicbook.com](https://www.facebook.com/comicbookdotcom/videos/1187582631402444/). In short, the strong implication is that his sword is made out of uru, the same material as Stormbreaker and Mjölnir.

> “Clearly Thanos is a thousand-year-old character who has fought
>   everyone in the universe and is the greatest: He’s the Genghis Khan of
>   the universe, so he would have the greatest weapon. **He knows of Eitri,
>   he’s been to Eitri to have his glove created. Did he have them create
>   his blade as well? Potentially. But it’s interesting that it could
>   destroy the shield.”**

Amplified by Thanos' raw strength, this would explain why it can cut through a material as resistant as vibranium with moderate ease.

Comment: If [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/marvelstudios/comments/bkoh9p/i_met_jim_starlin_today_and_he_confirmed_a_theory/) is to be believed the sword also allegedly comes from the Thanos Copter.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - Lol. I think that might be the writer making a little bit of fun; https://i.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/029/428/tod9xk5165h11.jpg

Answer (score 2):

In the commentary included with Avengers: Endgame.

> ..he was able to break his Vibranium shield because Eitri made his dual-edge sword from something much stronger. - [BGR](https://bgr.com/2019/08/01/avengers-endgame-digital-release-feature-explains-all-the-mysteries/)

[image]