# Vibranium Metallurgy

Tags: marvel, vibranium

What level of metallurgy skill is required to work and forge vibranium? Does the vibranium ore exhibit the same properties as forged items do, specifically the ability to absorb all vibrations? An ore that absorbs all vibrations presumably can't be hammered or mined, suggesting it would be extremely challenging to work. But that the Wakandans were able to not only create simple tools and primitive weapons with it but also found an advanced civilization upon it suggests that it is relatively simple to work with, perhaps easier than copper even.

Has it ever been described what it takes to work with vibranium?

Comment: Diamond can scratch other diamonds, so presumably they use vibramium and very high temperatures to forge vibranium?

Comment: Possible dupe of: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87474/why-is-captain-americas-shield-called-indestructible-if-vibranium-can-be-broken and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/73056/how-was-the-proto-adamantium-in-captain-americas-shield-forged/73057

Comment: The two questions are most certainly related, but asking from opposite sides of the theory I think. The other one is discussing the "indestructability" specifically, while this one is more asking about how the material is worked, obviously related, but not the same question exactly.

Comment: @eidylon The 2nd question I linked explicitly mentions forging of Adamantium/Vibranium, so this one is probably a dupe.

Comment: @Loki It's related, but it deals with how the metal was alloyed into Cap's shield, rather than how the metal is worked by itself.

Comment: @Xantec If it explains how the metal was forged into Cap's shield, what else is there to say!? Still, I'm eager to see if anyone has a better answer :)